# Can't figure out why matrix a doubles

Tags: java, junit

i am doing a school task where i use a provided JUnit Test to verify my coding and for some reason the returned matrix "tmp" is doubled the target matrix "speilet".

method :

```
package no.hvl.dat100.lab6.matriser;

public class Matriser {
        public static int[][] speile(int[][] matrise) {

        int[][] tmp = matrise;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrise.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matrise[i].length; j++) {

                tmp[i][j] = matrise[j][i];
            }
        }
        return tmp;
     }
```

JUnit test:

```
package no.hvl.dat100.lab6.matriser;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;



class MatriserEnhetsTester {

    private static int[][] a = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
//  private static int[][] b = { {10,11,12}, {13,14,15}, {16,17,18} };
    
    
    @Test
    void testSpeile() {
        
        int[][] speilet = { {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9} };
        
        assertArrayEquals(speilet,Matriser.speile(a));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what your function is supposed to do? And what do you mean by `is doubled the target matrix`?

Comment: You need to understand that matrix variables are effectively just references to matrix objects. `int[][] tmp = matrise;` does **not** create a new matrix, it merely assigns tmp a reference to the matrix that matrise also references. That means that with your current code `tmp[i][j] = matrise[j][i];` is effectively the same as `matrise[i][j] = matrise[j][i];`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.